# How can I debug when an app pool encounters fatal communication error that did not create dump file when crashing?

Tags: .net, iis, w3wp

An app pool is crashing with the error "A process serving application pool 'appPoolName' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was 'id'. The data field contains the error number."

When other app pools crash in that machine, they create a dump file and also log another event in the event viewer that says something like -
"Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.XXX.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8, time stamp: 0XXXXX
Exception code: 0xc00000fd"

What can crash the app pool without a dump file and without logging the faulting application name and details in the event viewer ?

Comment: A worker process talks to Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) via pipe. So when you see the "fatal communication error", it only indicates the pipe communication does not work properly so WAS thinks there is something wrong. Most common cause is of course w3wp crash as you know, but that's not the only cause as things like w3wp hang can also trigger such log entries. So if you really want to troubleshoot further, you should not only focus on crash dumps.

Comment: @Lex Li because a new worker process was spun off for that app pool, I had assumed that it crashed. If the process has hung, what kind of tools can I use to debug the cause?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure Use orphan related settings.